# tidyr::separate does'nt work with large data.frame

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a database with the following structure. I want to separate the last column, a part number and the other with the description, separating by "-". In the example it works ok. But when I use this in my database (50,700 cases) I get an error message.

```
      rut<-c("50001780", "50001810", "50001820",
             "50001850", "50001890", "50001940")
      econ.activ<-c("552010 - RESTAURANTES",                                    
      "930990 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.",
      "523911 - COMERCIO AL POR MENOR DE ARTICULOS FOTOGRAFICOS", 
      "930990 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.",
      "930990 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.",
      "930990 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.")

      df<-data.frame(rut,econ.activ)

      df %>% separate(col = "econ.activ", into = c("folio", "descripción"), sep = "\\-")
```

This is the error message

> Warning message:
>               Too many values at 174 locations: 3645, 4401, 5118, 10013, 10018, 10023, 10905, 10907, 10921, 10923, 10928, 10930, 10935, 10937, 10942, 10944, 11586, 13556, 13557, 13614, ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more than one `-` in some rows and that may be the reason for the warning.  One option is `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`.  It will split the 'econ.activ' into 'n' number of columns based on the maximum number (i.e. 'n') of '-' in a particular row.  By default, it will pad NA to columns if there are less number of '-' in certain rows.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "econ.activ", sep="-")
```

---

If we need to reproduce the warning, just insert another `-` in one of the elements

```
df$econ.activ <- as.character(df$econ.activ)
df$econ.activ[3] <- "930990 - OTRAS - SEP"
df %>% 
   separate(col = "econ.activ", into = c("folio", "descripción"), sep = "\\-")
---
---
```

> Warning message: Too many values at 1 locations: 3

It is because the `separate` have an argument `extra` which is by default `warn`.  There are other options like `drop` or `merge`.  If we use the `drop` it remove the substring from the second `-` onwards

```
df %>% 
  separate(col = "econ.activ", into = c("folio", "descripción"), sep = "\\-", extra="drop")
#       rut   folio                                       descripción
#1 50001780 552010                                       RESTAURANTES
#2 50001810 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
#3 50001820 930990                                             OTRAS 
#4 50001850 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
#5 50001890 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
#6 50001940 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
```

and with `extra = "merge"`, it retains that substring in the "descripción" column.  So, basically, it depends on what the OP wants as output

```
df %>% 
    separate(col = "econ.activ", into = c("folio", "descripción"), 
                 sep = "\\-", extra="merge")
#      rut   folio                                       descripción
#1 50001780 552010                                       RESTAURANTES
#2 50001810 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
#3 50001820 930990                                        OTRAS - SEP
#4 50001850 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
#5 50001890 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
#6 50001940 930990   OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS PERSONALES N.C.P.
```